# Make Startup Disk Does Not List DVD

Tags: boot, iso, dvd

I've made bootable Ubunbu disks many times but now the DVD writer does not appear in Startup Disk Creator in spite being mounted. I tried ejecting and letting it remount but to no avail. Any ideas or is there a different app that works better? I am running 22.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Startup Disk Creator to burn an ISO to a DVD. Startup Disk Creator is intended primarily for creating bootable USB media.

Any DVD authoring software should be able to write an ISO image to a DVD. You just need to make sure that the ISO is written as an *image* and not as a file.

I suggest using Brasero to write the ISO to a DVD.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I finally remembered that and have the disk burned.

Comment: I have a number of startup disks for earlier versions and am now using a freshly made Xubuntu disk but when I try to boot, all I get is a black screen with a flashing cursor. Same if I try to boot to USB stick but in that case I do get the Grub menu first asking what I want to do. Every choice gives the same black screen and cursor.